# Show decrypted values in combobox

Tags: vb.net, encryption, combobox

Im trying to show decrypted Us_User values of my SC_User table and i don't how to convert the datatable to string to use the DecryptDES function. The combo function:

```
Public Sub ToCombo(ByVal Combo As ComboBox)
    Dim encript As New SC_Encript
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim query As String = ""
    query = "Select Us_User From SC_User Order By (Us_User)ASC"
    ds = DataAccess.DSQuery(query, "SC_User")
    Combo.DisplayMember = "Us_User"
    Combo.ValueMember = "Us_User"
    'Combo.DataSource = encript.decryptDES(ds.Tables("SC_User") Obviously this line doesn't work , but shows the idea

End Sub
```

Any Help ?

Comment: I hope you r looking for a solution without For loop......With for loop its simple :)

Comment: I thought of a for but I do not know how to build it , how it is ?

Comment: Here u go.....For(int i=0;i<ds.table[0].rows.count;i++){//Decrypt the values here...and add in the combobox} ...